# Excel String Concatenation using " delimeter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to concatenate values from two columns and when I use `=CONCAT(A2,",",B2)` it will concatenate two columns with the correct result (P0810,P1). But what I am looking for is something like this ("P0810","P1"). I have tried `=CONCAT(""",A2,""",",",""",B2,""")` and I get this result `",A2,",",B2,"`
 So basically when I am trying to do this kind of concatenation it does not recognize the " delimeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEXTJOIN:

```
=""""&TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,A2:B2)&""""
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try using the ASCII code for a `"` and `,` character.

```
=CONCAT(char(34), A2, char(34)&char(44)&char(34), B2, char(34))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two double quotes result in a literal single double quote:

```
=CONCAT("""",A2,"""",",","""",B2,"""")
```